# Why code in C instead of C++

Tags: c++, c

Why code in C? Isn't C++ basically C but with better features? Why do people still use C? Would it be easier to make a game with C or C++?

Comment: Already answered in detail over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/497786/102937

Comment: Also [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/128995/c-vs-c-for-a-java-and-possibly-python-programmer/129008#comment634466_129008).  My comment there has a link to an external post that may be helpful as well.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based and opinions vary widely. For example, Linus Torvalds has a rather strong opinion one way while Bjarne Stroustrup has a rather strong opinion the other way.

Comment: [Yet another answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113295/when-to-use-c-over-c-and-c-over-c/160834#160834).

Answer (score 5):

C is used basically in embedded systems where using C++ is most of the time overkill and sometimes not possible. 
C++ is better suited for desktop applications and video games development. Most desktop apps are written in C++ (Chrome, Mozilla etc...) and the Windows OS is written in C++.
For video games it is much better to use C++ since the OOP aspect of the language makes it easy.